# I want to use broadcast receiver even if the app is closed

Tags: android

I am trying to show a toast message when receiving an incoming call/outgoing call. 
The receiver is not working if the app is closed. 
I do not want to use Service. Please help me out.

```
    'I am using the below receiver code'
    public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (isConnected(context)) {
                    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                         Toast.makeText(context, "Call in progress", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }

    'This is receiver registered in manifest'
    <receiver android:name="com.example.android.testapplication.CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.new_outgoing_call"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Fix your `<action>` elements. The second one, in particular, is not going to be recognized, as Android is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank u. I have fixed it. But still the receiver does not work if the app is closed.

Comment: I guess you need a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Comment: Is there any other way... Without using a service

Comment: You could use the NotificationManager, which is what you should use anyway instead of a Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the phone state permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default when you register a `BroadCastReceiver` with `AndroidOS` that means `Receiver` always work as the `Service` part even your application is not working, since you do not have to worry about this problem.
I think the problem is the way you register you `Receiver` was not correct.

With in/out coming call you should use PhoneStateListener which has overrided method onCallStateChanged. You can use 3 states over there.

Maybe [this example](https://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/manipulating-incoming-ougoing-calls-tutorial-for-android/) will be helpful.